# Print Key and List of corresponding Values

Tags: scala

I need to output an answer of the type `String, Iterable[String]` where `String` equals the key `3` and `Iterable[String]` is a list of `values` that correspond to the key `3`.

Given the following:

```
 Array[(String, String)] = Array((2,1), (2,1), (2,3), (2,3), (2,1), (2,4), (3,2), (2,2), (2,4), (3,2), (2,4), (2,3), (3,2), (3,2), (2,5), (2,5), (2,7), (2,1), (2,6), (3,3), (2,5), (3,2), (15,2), (3,2))
```

The answer should be:

```
3, [2,2,2,2,3,2,2]
```

Would anyone know how I can go about doing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by filtering on key and mapping:

```
def f(array:Array[Int], key:Int) = 
  (key, array.withFilter(_._1==key).map(_._2).toList)
```